# Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object on product without category URL

Tags: magento-1.7, product, products-management

When I disable a product and access the product by full category URL I am sent to a 404 page. Good.

When I attempt to access the disabled product by http://domain.com/disabled-product.html I get

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php on line 57
```

Could it be that an extension is attempting to load prior to the redirect?

**EDIT:** Lines 50-59

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
    $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
    if ($headBlock) {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
        if ($title) {
            $headBlock->setTitle($title);
        }
 ...
}
```

Comment: What extensions you have installed? Have someone edited the core classes?

Comment: Please add the code around line 57

Comment: I have added the code. I've just taken over this project so it is hard for me to say which files have and have not been touched. I assume it is a block loading without ensuring it is in the proper place - but I do not know that for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to a conflic with FME Ajax Add to cart.

I resolved by commenting out this rewrite in `/app/code/local/FME/Ajaxaddtocart/etc/config.xml`:

```
<!--
    Rewrite disabled because it conflicted with CreareSEO redirects
    <rewrite>

    <fme_ajaxaddtocart_productcontroller>
    <from><![CDATA[#^catalog/product/#]]></from>
    <to>/ajaxaddtocart/product/</to>
    </fme_ajaxaddtocart_productcontroller>

</rewrite> -->
```

Comment: If this was the solution, and it does seem like a more correct solution, why did you accept the other answer?

Answer (score 2):

Product is not an object, so try changing

```
if ($headBlock) {
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
    if ($title) {
        $headBlock->setTitle($title);
    }
```

To

```
if ($headBlock) {
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    if($product){
        $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
        if ($title) {
           $headBlock->setTitle($title);
         }
```

Comment: Can we assume that the root problem of this was a block loading out of order?

It seems like magento core should have this check in place.